# Rascal : NullPointerException at createM3FromEclipseProject

Tags: rascal

The following code with Rascal will not work:

```
module Exercise1

import IO;
import IO;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;

public void testing()
{
M3 model = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://JabberPoint/|);
for (<a,b> <- model.extends)
println("<a> extends <b>");
}
```

It results with:

```
|plugin://rascal_eclipse/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/lang/java/jdt/m3/Core.rsc|(392,187,<13,0>,<15,90>): Java("NullPointerException","")
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnitResolver.resolve(|unknown:///CompilationUnitResolver.java|(0,0,<599,0>,<599,0>))
        at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createASTs(|unknown:///ASTParser.java|(0,0,<906,0>,<906,0>))
        at org.rascalmpl.eclipse.library.lang.java.jdt.m3.internal.EclipseJavaCompiler.compileAllFiles(|unknown:///EclipseJavaCompiler.java|(0,0,<88,0>,<88,0>))....
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: this looks like a bug or at least an unclear error message; let's find a workaround, and continue the discussion on GitHub here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1452